# Styling contours at specific numbers

Tags: qgis, style, contour, qgis-2.8

I have a contour vector layer with a step 0.2m . I want every 1 metre, to change the line style, a thicker line for example, and the rest of them,symbolize with a dotted style. So, I can do it manually, categorize the layer, and at each metre,change the style, or I can copy the file, paste it and delete all the Real numbers, leave the integers only, and style them as I like and put the layer over the original. My question is if I can do the same job with the "Rule-base" style. If there is a formula which can locate the integer numbers and make them a category, so I can finish my job quicker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to do the following formula at Rule-based Style

```
"FieldName" % 1 = 0    (Assign thick lines for 1 meter interval lines)
ELSE                   (Assign thin lines or any other style for other interval lines)
```

[image]

In the above image "Elevation" is the name of the field that holds the contour elevation.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you ahmadhanb, also thank you for the explanation in the parenthesis.

Comment: You are most welcome. Glad it worked :)